# WPF extending a listview with styles and templates

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

Im trying to create an extended version of a ListView in .NET WPF.
I have a few more templates and styles then this I want to implement, but is stripped it down for testing purposes. How ever even these two dose not seem to work or load as nothing shows up of what has been configured.

The strange thing for me right now, is that these work when put in a user control, with a regular ListView and use the same type of `StaticResource` reference.
How ever, I thought it would be possible to put these in a shared xaml and cs file for better reusability.

Am I setting this up wrong for a specified type of ListView?

XAML

```
<ListView x:Class="MyProject.SharedView.ExtListView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">


<ListView.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ArColumnHeaderContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Control.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Control.VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Gray" />
    </Style>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ArColumnHeaderTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <DockPanel Name="dpQColHead" Grid.Row="0">
                <CheckBox/>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Red" TextTrimming="None" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <Binding />
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </DockPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.Resources>

<ListView.View>
    <GridView 
        ColumnHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ArColumnHeaderTemplate}"
        ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ArColumnHeaderContainerStyle}">
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

CS

```
    public partial class ExtListView : ListView
{
    public ExtListView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.AddHandler(
            GridViewColumnHeader.ClickEvent,
            new RoutedEventHandler(GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler));
    }

    private GridViewColumnHeader _lastHeaderClicked = null;
    private ListSortDirection _lastDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;



    /// <summary>
    /// Sort data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sortBy"></param>
    /// <param name="direction"></param>
    private void Sort(string sortBy, ListSortDirection direction)
    {
        ICollectionView dataView =
          CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.ItemsSource);

        if (dataView != null)
        {
            dataView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
            SortDescription sd = new SortDescription(sortBy, direction);
            dataView.SortDescriptions.Add(sd);
            dataView.Refresh();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event, Grid column header clicked
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewColumnHeader headerClicked = e.OriginalSource as GridViewColumnHeader;
        ListSortDirection direction;

        if (headerClicked != null &&
            headerClicked.Role != GridViewColumnHeaderRole.Padding)
        {
            if (_lastHeaderClicked != null)
            {
                ColumnAdorner.RemoveAdorner(_lastHeaderClicked);
            }

            if (headerClicked != _lastHeaderClicked)
            {
                direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
            }
            else
            {
                if (_lastDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                {
                    direction = ListSortDirection.Descending;
                }
                else
                {
                    direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
                }
            }

            // see if we have an attached SortPropertyName value
            string sortBy = GetSortPropertyName(headerClicked.Column);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy))
            {
                // otherwise use the column header name
                sortBy = headerClicked.Column.Header as string;
            }
            Sort(sortBy, direction);

            _lastHeaderClicked = headerClicked;
            _lastDirection = direction;

            ColumnAdorner.SetAdorner(headerClicked, direction);
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Custom sorting property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SortPropertyNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SortPropertyName", typeof(string), typeof(AriesListView));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets property
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetSortPropertyName(GridViewColumn obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(SortPropertyNameProperty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set property name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    public static void SetSortPropertyName(GridViewColumn obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SortPropertyNameProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Running the custom ListView

```
 ...
      <sv:ArListView
         BorderBrush="#b7d9ed" BorderThickness="1"
         VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
                                VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" 
         Grid.Row="1" Margin="4,4,0,0" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TargetObject.AssignedClassification.ExternalStandardMappings}"
                                GridViewColumnHeader.Click="SortGridViewByColumn">
          <sv:ArListView.View>
              <GridView>
                 <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Standard.Name}" Header="Standard" Width="100"/>          
              <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ID}" Header="ID" Width="Auto"/>
           <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Description}" Header="Description" Width="Auto"/>
                                       
        </GridView>
     </sv:ArListView.View>
  </sv:ArListView>
...
```

Comment: How is `ExtListView.xaml.cs` defined and how are you testing/using the `ListView`?

Comment: Have updated the post with both code behind and how it is included in another usercontrol.

Comment: And what exactly is "not working"? What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: The `ArColumnHeaderTemplate` is not being used. There is no red text and no checkbox showing up.

Comment: That's because you are setting the `View` property to a completely different `GridView` in the `UserControl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XAML markup creates an instance of the `ListView` and sets its `GridView` property to a completely new `GridView` which means that the `GridView` that you have defined in ExtListView.xaml.cs will be overwritten:

```
<sv:ArListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Standard.Name}" Header="Standard" Width="100"/>          
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ID}" Header="ID" Width="Auto"/>
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Description}" Header="Description" Width="Auto"/>                   
    </GridView>
<sv:ArListView.View>
```

If you handle the `Loaded` event for the `ListView`, you should be able to set the `ColumnHeaderTemplate` and `ColumnHeaderContainerStyle` properties *after* the `View` property has been set:

```
public partial class ExtListView : ListView
{
    public ExtListView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.AddHandler(
            GridViewColumnHeader.ClickEvent,
            new RoutedEventHandler(GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler));

        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gridView = View as GridView;
        if (gridView != null)
        {
            gridView.ColumnHeaderTemplate = Resources["ArColumnHeaderTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
            gridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle = Resources["ArColumnHeaderContainerStyle"] as Style;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ooh, thank you! You'r absolutely right. 
It works!